# Is It Possible To Make a Geometrical Object

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to make a geometrical object that is split into 27 individual segments, like a Rubix cube, only with all segments being identical, and all segments sharing the same amount of visible faces on the surface?

Basically: To make a Rubix cube-like object that could have its sides rotated by 45 degrees and still have the same shape?

Comment: What do you mean by "segment"?

Comment: Note that the Rubik's cube technically has less than $27$ "segments". Physically we have $12_{\text{edges}}+8_{\text{corners}}+1_{\text{central part}}=21$ parts.

Comment: Let's say you take a cube: You slice it three times along the x,y and z axis, and you have a Rubix cube, right? While these individual pieces are identical, they don't all look the same from the outside; the corner pieces have three sides showing, and the middle pieces only have two or one side showing. Is there a way to make a shape that, split in the same fashion, would have each part look the same?

Comment: I see what you mean. You have two problems: (1) define what exactly "looks the same from the outside" means, and (2) define what exactly "split in the same fashion" means.

Comment: I'm a complete noob to this and I'm completely out of my element in asking this, so please forgive me if what I say is stupid; 

That being said, it might be easier to explain it the other way around: Let's say I wanted to make an object out of 26 geometrical elements (omitting the center element); each element being identical, and without any holes in the surface of the compound object. Each element would have to be angled in 45 degrees to the neighbouring elements along all axis'.

Does that make sense, and if yes, is that possible?

Comment: Something like a [Rhombicuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) or a [Truncated cuboctahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_cuboctahedron) but with all faces looking the same? There's no such thing.